The comand ee.ImageCollection.combine() to join collections returns a blank collection
I am trying to combine two distinct image collections (Sentinel 1 and 2) using the .combine() command suggested in a previous post.
I resampled the pixels to 10m
I created an internal identifier for each collection using a function that shows which week the image was taken, with the purpose of combining two images collected in the same week. This identifier will be used to combine the compatible images from both collections
When I use combine() to merge the two collections, I get a blank final collection, even with the week identifier, to show the similarities.
What could be wrong?
the official documentation shows this:

"Makes a new collection that is a copy of the images in primary,
adding all the bands from the image in secondary with a matching ID.
If there are no matching IDs, the resulting collection will be empty.
This is equivalent to an inner join on ID with merging of the bands of
the result. Note that this algorithm assumes that for a matching pair
of inputs, both have the same footprint and metadata."

Could the metadata be the cause of the equivalence problem, because they are different?
my code example
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
[[-54.78753991320279,-20.76018247385302],
[-54.44421715929654,-20.76018247385302],
[-54.44421715929654,-20.528863542361954],
[-54.78753991320279,-20.528863542361954],
[-54.78753991320279,-20.76018247385302]])

Map.addLayer(poly, {}, 'poly')
Map.centerObject(poly, 10)

// Load Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 Image Collections
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select(['VV', 'VH'])
.map(function(image){
  return image.float()})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(poly)
});

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
.map(function(image){
  return image.float()})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(poly)
});

//resample to 10m all collections
var resample = function (image){
return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
crs: s2.first().projection().crs(),
scale: 10})}

//add resample fucntion
var s1r = s1.map(resample)
var s2r = s2.map(resample)

print(s1r, 's1r')
print(s2r,  's2r')


//add weeks reference  from unix date
var week = function(image) { 
  var referenceDate = ee.Date('1970-01-01'); 
  var weeks = image.date().difference(referenceDate, 'day').divide(7); 
  return image.set('weeks_since_reference', weeks); }; 

var s1k =s1r.map(week)
var s2k =s2r.map(week)
print(s1k, 's1k')

var combined = s1k.combine(s2k)

print(combined, 'combined')


The combine() function matches up images based on the image ID.  In your case, you haven't done anything to the IDs, so there are no matches between the two collections.  You could try to fiddle with the image IDs to make this work, but I think you're fundamentally headed down the wrong path.
A better approach would be to map over weeks and filter to find the images that fall into each week (you might have more than 1 image per week).  You then mosaic those images and just add their bands together.
var start = ee.Date("2020-01-01")
var weeks = ee.List.sequence(0, 52)
var mosaics = weeks.map(function(wk) {
    var t1 = start.advance(wk, "week")
    var t2 = t1.advance(1, "week")
    var s1mosaic = s1.filterDate(t1, t2).mosaic()
    var s2mosaic = s2.filterDate(t1, t2).mosaic()
    return s1mosaic.addBands(s2mosaic).set({
      "week": wk,
      "system:id": ee.Number(wk).format("week_%d")
    })
})


this works, it creates a list of images, which I later converted for collection using var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection(mosaics), thanks
